# why my submit input isn't working in django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have a form so an user can ask for a loan and it will tell them if it´s approved or not. The problem is not the logic, it´s the submit input that doesn't work. It will not save the form in the database or show me the errors because of the submit input. Maybe is something wrong with the succes_url? I don't know, but here's my code:

views.py:

```
#don't worry about the logic part of the form, it's just to show how it´s supposed to work




class LoanRequest(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    form_class = LoanForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('Prestamos')
    template_name = 'Prestamos/template/Prestamos/prestamos.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = self.request.user
        cliente = Cliente.objects.get(user_id = user.id)
        if not cliente.approve_loan(form.cleaned_data.get('loan_total')):
            form.add_error(field=None, error='loan not approved')
            return self.form_invalid(form)
        else:
            form.instance.customer_id = cliente
            super(LoanRequest, self).form_valid(form)
            return render(self.request, 'Prestamos/template/Prestamos/prestamos.html', context={'form': form, 'success_msg': 'loan approved!'})
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('prestamos/', views.LoanRequest.as_view(), name = 'prestamos'),
]
```

forms.py:

```
class LoanForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Prestamo #loan in English
        fields = ['loan_type', 'loan_total', 'loan_date']
```

and the template:

```
<div class="container">
            {%if success_msg%}
                <p class="alert alert-success">{{success_msg}}</p>
            {%endif%}
            <form action="" method="POST">
                {%csrf_token%}
                {%for field in form%}
                    <div class="form-group">    
                        <label for="{{field.label}}">{{field.label}}</label>
                        {{field}}
                    </div>
                    {%for error in field.errors%}
                      <p>{{error}}</p>
                    {%endfor%}
                {%endfor%}
                <input type="submit" value="request"></input>
            </form>
        </div>
```

models.py:

```
class Prestamo(models.Model):
    loan_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    loan_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, 
    choices = [('PERSONAL', 'PERSONAL'), ('HIPOTECARIO', 'HIPOTECARIO'), ('PRENDARIO', 'PRENDARIO')])
    loan_date = models.DateField()
    loan_total = models.IntegerField()
    customer_id = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'prestamo'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `<input>` is an empty tag, it does not contain anything, so don't close it.

Additionally, I'd recommend you to make gaps between template tags, like it should be `{% endfor %}` not <s>`{%endfor%}`</s>.

Also, remove the empty `action` attribute from form, as Django always take current page route if not mentioned or empty string.

Also use `novalidate` on form for rendering custom errors.

Try this template:

```html
<div class="container">
            {% if success_msg %}
                <p class="alert alert-success">{{success_msg}}</p>
            {% endif %}
            <form method="POST" novalidate>
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% for field in form %}
                    <div class="form-group">    
                        <label for="{{field.label}}">{{field.label}}</label>
                        {{field}}
                    </div>
                    {% for error in field.errors %}
                      <p>{{error}}</p>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
                <input type="submit" value="request">
            </form>
</div>
```

### Edit:

One mistake I could see the name for the view is `prestamos` and you have mentioned it as `Prestamos`, which is wrong.

So:

```
class LoanRequest(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    form_class = LoanForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('prestamos')
    template_name = 'Prestamos/template/Prestamos/prestamos.html'
```

Comment: Hi, I've just tried it but it doesn´t seem to work. It keeps having the same error

Comment: @MaximilianoRodriguez what error?

Comment: @MaximilianoRodriguez Would you also please share your models?

Comment: i mean error as not showing me anything. And sure, I´ve just edited the question to show the models.py

Comment: @MaximilianoRodriguez Where is approve_loan() function? Does the form also not appearing or the issue is only  with saving of form into db? Also share Cliente model.

Comment: @MaximilianoRodriguez See the edited answer, it should be `prestamos` not `Prestamos` in reverse_lazy :) Addtionally I'd recommend you to use template namespacing correctly, like templates must have the path as `templates/your_app_name/any_template_file.html`.

Comment: approve loan function is in another model, the issue is that when i click the request input it doesn´t happen anything, not even an error or something, it just stays still the page

Comment: Thanks for the reverse_lazy but nothing happened

Comment: @MaximilianoRodriguez Try to restart the server in another port through `python manage.py runserver 2000`.